# How to have generics and constant function return type based on parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Say that I want the function `input` to return the constant type ({ ... } and not the closest type `object`) of the first parameter `obj`.
Then Ex.1 will not work, because the the parameter type is `object` and the return type will be `object` too. Ex.2 will work because the parameter is `T` which only have to extend object.

Now here is the problem with Ex.3, I want to specify a generic type but still have the parameter to extend type `object` (and not be type `object`). I also tried to make two separate functions one with only the generic type to be explicitly typed and another with both the the generic type to be explicitly typed and the generic to extend object in Ex.4, however this doesn't work and I don't know why. Any ideas how to fix this?

**tl;dr** I want to infer the function parameter, but still have to option to pass a generic.

#### Ex. 1

**Doesn't work, invalid type**

```
// object
const output = input({
    property: 123
})

function input(obj: object) {
    return obj
}
```

#### Ex.2

**Works, but no extra generics**

```
// { property: number }
const output = input({
    property: 123
})

function input<T>(obj: T): T {
    return obj
}
```

#### Ex.3

**Doesn't work, errors**

```
// [ERROR]: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.
const output = input<{
    another: 'property'
}>({
    property: 123
})

function input<T1, T2>(obj: T2): T1 & T2 {
    return modify(obj)
}
```

#### Ex.4

**Doesn't work, invalid type**

```
// object
const output = input<{
    another: 'property'
}>({
    property: 123
})

function _input<T1, T2>(obj: T2): T1 & T2 {
    return modify(obj)
}

function input<T1>(obj: object) {
    return _input(obj)
}
```

Comment: So you want to specify one parameter and let the other one be inferred?

Comment: @blaumeise20 yes

Comment: I’m confused.  What does the modify function do?

Comment: @LindaPaiste `modify` will add `T2` to `T1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is currently not possible. There is a proposal on GitHub which you can see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) but it seems like it will take some time for it to be implemented.